# Rails using group and order to query associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to grab those `author` records whose most expensive book is located at the bookstore: `bookworm`.

Below are my associations:

```
#app/models/author.rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

#app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book_store
end

#app/models/book_store.rb
class BookStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

And part of the database schema to show table columns:

```
#db/schema.rb 
create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "book_stores", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "store_name"
end

create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.integer  "cost"
  t.integer  "author_id"
  t.integer  "book_store_id"
end
```

As I process this query I think I should do something like the following:

1. `join` the `author` , `book` , `book_store` tables

   ```
   @authors_books = Author.joins(books: :book_store)
   ```
2. `order` by `author_id, cost`

   ```
   #first should order by author_id. Then, for author_id ties: it orders by cost in descending order
   @authors_books = @authors_books.order("author_id ASC, cost DESC")
   ```
3. `group` by author_id, check the very first record for that author. If its `book_store.store_name == 'bookworm'` then return it.

   ```
   #struggling with this part for sure:
   @authors_books = @authors_books.group(:author_id).having("min(book_store.name) like 'bookworm'")
   ```

Afterwards, `@authors_books` should be a list of `uniq` author records whose most expensive book is located at the bookstore: `bookworm`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this.  First, create a class method on the Book model to get the most expensive books by author:

```
# Book model
def self.max_by_author
  max_costs = group(:author_id).select("author_id, MAX(cost) AS max_cost")
  joins("INNER JOIN (#{max_costs.to_sql}) max_costs ON books.author_id = max_costs.author_id AND books.cost = max_costs.max_cost")
end
```

Then you can use `merge` to combine this with BookStore and Author queries to get what you need.  To find the max books that are sold at "bookworm" you can use:

```
Book.max_by_author.joins(:book_store).merge(BookStore.where(store_name: "bookworm"))
```

To find the authors of the max books that are sold at "bookworm" you can use:

```
Author.joins(:books).merge(Book.max_by_author.joins(:book_store).merge(BookStore.where(store_name: "bookworm"))).uniq
```